# I am stuck in determining whether BLE device is connectable or not, by analyzing advertisement data. Here is my code sample and study guide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am using Ionic React. And Advertising data received from device was in ArrayBuffer format, from ArrayBuffer I took UInt8Array and then parsed it using following function:

```
function asHexString(i: any) {
    var hex;

    hex = i.toString(16);

    // zero padding
    if (hex.length === 1) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }

    return "0x" + hex;
}

export const parseAdvertisingData = (buffer: any) => {
    var length, type, data, i = 0, advertisementData = {};
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);

    while (length !== 0) {

        length = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
        i++;

        // decode type constants from https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile
        type = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
        i++;

        data = bytes.slice(i, i + length - 1).buffer; // length includes type byte, but not length byte
        i += length - 2;  // move to end of data
        i++;

        // @ts-ignore
        advertisementData[asHexString(type)] = data;
    }

    return advertisementData;
}
```

This returned Object of ArrayBuffer, one with key 0x19(APPEARANCE DATA) and other 0xff(MANUFACTURER DATA)

Then I converted both ArrayBuffer->UInt8Array to hex string and got following results:

Advertisement Raw Data Received: 0x031919001AFF580015E8FF000000000C0C0011D40000000000000001010000

| Len | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0x19 | 0x1900 |
| 26 | 0x26 | 0x580015E8FF000000000C0C0011D40000000000000001010000 |

Now, I wanted to determine whether this device is connectable or not from above results??

*Following are study material:*

**Legacy Advertising PDUs**

These are available for all Bluetooth versions – also enables backward compatibility with older versions and are used on the Primary advertising channels.

- ADV_IND: Connectable Scannable Undirected advertising.
- ADV_DIRECT_IND: Connectable Directed advertising
- ADV_NONCONN_IND: Non-Connectable Non-Scannable Undirected advertising
- ADV_SCAN_IND: Scannable Undirected advertising

[image]

[image]

Reference:

1. BLE GAP CHART: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/
2. BLE ADVERTISEMENT: https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-low-energy-advertisements-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

The advertisement data in the buffer you are examining is part of the payload and does not contain information from the PDU header. The PDU type indicates if it's connectable or not. I don't know how what BLE features are exposed in your javascript BLE lib, but at least on Android you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult#isConnectable() to determine if it's connectable or not.

Comment: This package is used

Comment: That library does not expose isConnectable, which should otherwise be done here: https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/blob/c33d5a60165d24ae4c1392ae7d9f25f653e7adb2/src/android/BLECentralPlugin.java#L665.

Comment: But that is java code, I need to do this in JavaScript

Comment: You could modify the library so that it exposes the feature you want, or write your own library, or write your app in Java.